# Problem writing a function in R that uses tidyr's "gather" to convert similar data-frames to long format

Tags: r, function, tidyr

I am trying to write a function, which uses tidyr's gather, and which I can use to convert multiple, similar data-frames to long form. I have written a basic function that successfully converts to long form, but I also want the function to name the "value" column, and this is where I have difficulty.

I have searched for some time on the internet, but because gather itself is a function, every search I do using some variant of "write function..." and "gather" just leads me to pages showing me how to use the function gather in tidyr. I know how to use gather. What I want to do is use "gather" in a separate function.

Here is some example code:

```
df <- data.frame(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Albania"),
                 Indicator = "emissions",
                 '1960' = rnorm(3, mean = 0.5, sd =1),
                 '1961' = rnorm(3, mean = 0.5, sd =1),
                 '1962' = rnorm(3, mean = 0.5, sd =1))

colnames(df) <- c("Country", "Indicator", "1960", "1961", "1962")
```

Yes, I am deliberately changing the last three columns names to years, but datatype character. The data I am using (from the World Bank Data Bank) comes likes this.

Here is function:

```
convert_to_longform <- function(df_name1, value_name1, year1, year2) {
  gather(df_name1, key = Year, value = value_name1, c(year1:year2))

}

df_lf <- convert_to_longform(df, emissions, "1960", "1962")
```

So this function works, but as you see, the column name for the value column becomes "value_name1", when I want the column name to be "emissions". Is there a way to set the name of the value column using gather inside a separate function?

My expected result is a long form dataframe where the value column is "emissions" or some other character string I designate and not value_name1.

Comment: What happens if you do `"emissions"` instead of `emissions`?

Comment: I did try various variations on this (quoting or not quoting). I should have said so in my question, so sorry about that. The answer below solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify the name of the value column if you unquote the argument with `!!`:

(See docs on [Quasiquotation of an expression](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html))

```
convert_to_longform <- function(df_name1, value_name1, year1, year2) {
 gather(df_name1, key = Year, value = !!value_name1, c(year1:year2))
}

convert_to_longform(df, "emissions", "1960", "1962")



#        Country Indicator Year   emissions
#  1 Afghanistan emissions 1960  0.68329845
#  2      Angola emissions 1960  0.13857468
# ...
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! Thanks also for the link on quasiquotation.